# Why is my laptop’s CPU not running at base speed and underclocking itself?

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

I noticed my laptop performance dropping so I checked the CPU cores speed and found out it is underclocking as you can see also when I put the CPU on stress it is not changing not even going to 100%.

My laptop is Asus K56C and I'm using Windows 10

Also I've checked my power options CPU maximum performance is set to 100%.

[image: CPU Spec]

[image: CPU-z Stress Test]

[image: Temps]

[Thread checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jmdf.jpg)

Comment: What stress test are you running? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Comment: @DavidPostill CPU-Z app multithread test i've uploaded screen shot

Comment: It's only using 40% of your CPU ...

Comment: guess it is being throttled

Comment: Please edit your question: What is the exact make and model of the laptop?

Comment: Try with the _Threads_ checkbox checked

Comment: no change added the sc

Comment: Max package temp of 59°C is low, did you set that in the BIOS? TJunc is 105°C

Comment: If the graphics card or another sensor on the motherboard are hot then it might be limiting that way. Try looking through questions at https://superuser.com/search?q=prochot

Comment: Have you rebooted your laptop? **Not shutdown, reboot.** Also have a look at the program `throttlestop` and the search I linked might show some help.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? What's the state of the speed step in the BIOS?

Comment: Even with the max perf cap in power options, you may still see this if you have the laptop's *fan* setting to {whatever they call it}: the options are something along the lines of "use fan and be super loud" and "throttle cpu before using super loud fan."

Answer (score 0):

I've entered my BIOS and Loaded the Default values for the BIOS setting after restarting speed Frequency got fixed and Utilization increased to 80% under stress(Don't know if it should get to 100%) also base speed in the task manager is 2.5Gh but in my CPU spec it is 2.0Gh .

[image: New]